# Problem passing XML Parameter to SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a stored procedure that accepts XML data as an input parameter but cannot get it to compile. The Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.idn_UpdateUserApplications
(
    @AppIdList xml,
    @UserID nvarchar(256),
    @ModifiedBy nvarchar(256)
)

AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO userapplication 
                (userid, 
                 modifiedby, 
                 modifiedon,
                 appid) 
    SELECT @UserID as userid, 
           @ModifiedBy As modifiedby, 
           Getdate() as modifiedon,
           paramvalues.id.VALUE('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS appid 
    FROM   @AppIdList.NODES('/Applications/id') AS paramvalues(ID)   
END
```

The Error:
Msg 317, Level 16, State 1, Procedure idn_UpdateUserApplications, Line 13
Table-valued function 'NODES' cannot have a column alias.

Comment: I forgot to mention - this is SQL 2005 so I cannot use table valued parameters - darn !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NODES` and `VALUE` needs to be lower case `nodes`, `value`.

Comment: That was it - can't believe SQL Server is that lame (and I love SQL Server)